# Parameters with new where queries in Grails 2.0

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Is it possible to use parameters when defining a where query in Grails 2.0? For example:

```
def query = Book.where {
   id == it
}
Book sub = query.find(5)
```

I tried running that code, but it throws a MissingMethodException on the call to find. I also tried defining a variable before it, but it doesn't seem to work (as find returns null, even though I know it exists).

```
Long someId = 5
def query = Book.where {
   id == someId
}
Book sub = query.find()
```

Any tricks? Being able to dynamically change the parameters of the query would be extremely useful.

(I know I could just use Book.get(5), but for simplicity sake, this seemed like the easiest example to pick)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like the way to do this is to define a closure as detachCriteria,

```
import grails.gorm.*

def callable = { id -> 
    id == id
} as DetachedCriteria<Book>

def query = Book.where( callable( id: 5 ) )
```

Comment: Looks like it should work, but when I tried it, still wouldn't go (MissingMethodException, complaining that there was no eq method). Also changed the parameter to be someId so it wasn't trying to compare itself to itself, and tried callable(5) (without a map), all with no luck. I think the answer is, you have to use namedQueries to do this. Unfortunate, because the new where syntax is so nice!